# Cannot browse to site hosted in IIS Express even though successfully registered

Tags: asp.net, iis-express

I'm trying to run an ASP.NET Core MVC application (100% template) in IIS Express. It seems the site is already hosted in IIS Express, but when I open the site in browser, I got the generic error "This site can't be reached". Any idea?

From Visual Studio:

```
Starting IIS Express ...
Successfully registered URL "http://localhost:55516/" for site "WebApplication1" application "/"
Successfully registered URL "https://localhost:44331/" for site "WebApplication1" application "/"
Registration completed for site "WebApplication1"
IIS Express is running.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
```

Looking at DevTool, this is the response I got:

[image]

My launchSettings.json:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:55516",
      "sslPort": 44331
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "WebApplication1": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: Interestingly, would not run if I F5 from VS. If I run "dotnet run" from CLI, it runs perfectly fine... Why???

Comment: No exceptions thrown?

Comment: which browser do you use?

Comment: Tried with Brave, Edge, none are working. No exception, not even an error in the Event Viewer. Just the application not running. I'm suspecting something to do with corporate's AV, or whatever crap they are running, but I have nothing to prove to them.

Comment: can you show your launchSettings.json file?

Comment: please make anonymousAuthentication=true and also windowsAuthentication=false